# How to fix error "searchParams.userId" And I can’t upload the project to either Netfly or Vercel

Tags: typescript, react-fullstack

How to fix error "searchParams.userId"
And I can’t upload the project to either Netfly or Vercel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_-b_isI4vg&t=536s&ab_channel=CodeWithAntonio

I did everything for this project. But I caught this mistake. And how can I fix it?

I don't know where it came from yet

Comment: Please give a [mre], of one specific problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"` at the top of the page.tsx in the app directory of the program.

This fixed it for me. The issue occurs in versions Next 13.3 and up. I found the answer in the GitHub issues tab for this project.

https://github.com/AntonioErdeljac/next13-airbnb-clone/issues/48